# I want to fetch stagename value after select opportunity name from the picklist using lightning in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

[image: I got error message when loading page]

```
onchange:  function (component, event) 
{
    var nums = []; 
    var data = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    var num=component.get("v.number");
    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
    {
        nums.push({data[i].name});  **//error comes here**
    }
     component.set("v.oppnames", nums);              
    var parentName = component.get("v.oppnames");
    var compEvents = component.getEvent("componentEventFired");
   compEvents.setParams({ "context" : parentName });
    compEvents.fire();
},
```

[image: I want to fetch stagename value after select opportunity name from the picklist using lightning in salesforce]

Component:

```
<select id="mySelect" class="slds-select" name="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}" change="{!c.onchange}">
    <!--<lightning:Select aura:id="mySelect1" value="{!v.selectedValue}" change="{!c.onchange}" >-->
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item1">

        <option text="{!item1.label }" value="{!item1.name }" selected="{!item1.selected}"/>

         </aura:iteration>
           <!-- </lightning:Select>-->

    </select>

<div class="head slds-container--large">Stgae Name</div> 
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.formats}" var="wrap" indexVar="idx1">
 <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx1,3)}">

     <ui:outputText value="{!wrap.stagename}" aura:id="reason"/>
     <div class="slds-container--large slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--center">
        <ui:outputText value="{!v.prds}" aura:id="reason"/>
     </div>
```

Controllerjs:

```
handleComponentEventFired : function(component, event) {
    var context = event.getParam("context");
    component.set("v.prds", context);
    },

    onchange:  function (component, event) 
    {
       var mapVar = component.get("v.myMap");
        function addValuestoMap(key, value) {
        mapVar[key] = value;
        }
        function mapValueIsList(key, value) {
        mapVar[key] = [] || map[key];
        mapVar[key].push(value);
    }
        var tempList =component.get("v.options");
        for(var i=0;i<tempList.length;i=i+1) {
        mapValueIsList(tempList[i], i);
    }
        component.set("v.myMap", mapVar);


       var parentName = component.get("v.selectedValue");
       //var parentName = component.get("v.myMap");
       var compEvents = component.getEvent("componentEventFired");
       compEvents.setParams({ "context" : parentName });
        compEvents.fire();
     },
```

Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
   public static list<opportunity> getProductByName() {
        list<opportunity> options= [select id, name from opportunity ];
        return options;
    }
   @AuraEnabled
   public static Map<string,string> getstageName() {
        Map<string,string> mapstr=new Map<string,string>();
        for(opportunity o:[select id, stagename,name from opportunity])
        {
            mapstr.put(o.name,o.stagename);

        }
        return mapstr;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, but, do you think you can point out where you are trying to achieve this in it, or what you have tried? where you are stuck, what is the current behavior and the one you were expecting? This will increase your chances of getting help from others on the forum, thanks!

Comment: **I don't have any idea to write the code and i tried onchange event to fetch stagename.My requirement is when i select opportunity name then then stage name will be fetch from related opportunity name.
i tried on action that is:

onchange:  function (component, event)

Comment: please update your question with details rather than posting it in a comment for others to better comprehend what you have tried and where you are stuck. Thanks